# Upgrading from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2 and running legacy DTS packages

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can we run a legacy DTS package written for and currently running on an instance of SQL Server 2000 on a server running SQL Server 2008 R2?

We have a database that we know will run fine on SQL Server 2008 R2 but the legacy DTS package is causing us concern in migrating. We would even consider an alternative that included loading components of SQL Server 2000 just to have the ability to run this DTS package.

Comment: Just as a look into the future: SQL Server 2008 R2 is the **last** version to still support DTS packages - with SQL Server 2011 "Denali", you will have to convert to SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import DTS packages old format (*.dts) into SQL Server 2008R2 from Management > Legacy > Data Transformation Services.

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN article [Migrating DTS Packages to Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768544%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

> **Support for DTS in SQL Server 2008**
>
> DTS packages can still run as before when you have the SQL Server 2008
>   database engine installed. To accomplish this, you must have the
>   Microsoft SQL Server Backward Compatibility feature installed from the
>   SQL Server installation media or the Feature Pack Web page. This
>   installs the DTS runtime for SQL Server 2008, which works on 32-bit
>   platforms only.
>
> If you perfom an in-place upgrade from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server
>   2008, then all the DTS packages stored locally will be preserved as
>   DTS packages in SQL Server 2008. The upgrade process does not
>   automatically migrate DTS packages to the Integration Services format.
>   To edit the DTS packages, you must have the Microsoft SQL Server 2000
>   DTS Designer Component installed, which is part of the SQL Server 2005
>   Feature Pack and is a separate download from the Microsoft website.
>
> You can manage your DTS packages from SQL Server Management Studio
>   under the Management à Legacy à Data Transformation Services node.
>   Here, you can open existing DTS packages stored on the file system or
>   in the msdb database, or add additional packages to the server by
>   clicking the Import button. New DTS packages cannot be created from
>   Management Studio, but old packages can be modified and renamed.

Comment: we are going to be using SQL 2008 R2 Web Edition (64-bit).  Do you know of these DTS packages are compatible with the Web Additions and if there is an upgrade path from 2000 DTS packages to this version?